Weird behaviour with SpriteBatch.Draw in MonoGame
I'm creating a rhythm game. I'm trying to move automatically Notes from upside but something went wrong. Notes just stuck.

Below is code, thanks in advance for help because I don't understand what I'm did bad.
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    gameTime = gameTime;

    soundEngine = new SoundEngineXact();
    soundEngine.Initialize(game);

    keyboardListener = new LowLevelKeyboardListener();
    keyboardListener.OnKeyPressed += KeyboardListener_OnKeyPressed;

    keyboardListener.HookKeyboard();

    soundEngine.Update();

    foreach (var gameplayObject in gameplayObjects)
    {
        gameplayObject.Update(gameTime, spriteBatch, contentManager);
        
    }
}

public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    mainMenuBackground = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
    pianoTexture = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("Piano");

    spriteBatch.Draw(mainMenuBackground, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(pianoTexture, new Vector2(100, 0), Color.White);

    spriteBatch.End();

    foreach (var gameplayObject in gameplayObjects)
    {
        gameplayObject.Draw(spriteBatch, contentManager);
    }
}

public abstract class GameplayObject
{
    public int Time { get; protected set; }
    public int Position { get; protected set; }

    public GameplayObject(int time, int position)
    {
        Time = time;
        Position = position;
    }

    public abstract void Update(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager contentManager);

    public abstract void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager contentManager);
}

public class Note : GameplayObject
{
    public float FallSpeed = 100.0f;
    private int x;

    public Note(int time, int x, int position) : base(time, position)
    {
        this.Position = position;
        this.x = x;
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager contentManager)
    {
        float newY = Position + (float)(gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds * FallSpeed);
        Position = (int)newY;
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager contentManager)
    {
        // Here is something wrong, notes should move dynamically but they don't
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("NoteTexture"), new Vector2(x, Position), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}


Did the notes move before getting stuck, or were they stuck at the moment you load up the game? I assume it's the latter for now.
The draw code seem to look fine so far. But I think the problem lies on updating the position variable.
Maybe gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds is not a dynamic increasing number? Or the convert between float to int may result into the same number constantly, as int doesn't keep the decimals. You might want to try debugging that part if it works correctly

Hi there! At the moment when beatmap with this objects are selected. Weirdly, position variable and gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds works normally.

Maybe I could give some other tips: 1) The spritebatch.Begin and .End within the GamplayObject.Draw could be removed, and then the foreach loop could be placed within the Spritebatch.Begin of the Game1 class. 2) Loading Texture2D's only needs to happen once, so you could make them a Texture2D variable and place them inside an Init() Method (Like where the gameplay objects are initialised), and then move them away from the draw method. Both tips help to reduce the workload inside the Draw method, and perhaps they may fix the problem too.
